# Loop can't process array

Tags: excel, vba

I apologize for the vague title as I'm not really sure where the error is. I think I'm having some compability issues with copying the elements of an array and then manipulating that data.

This is the code I have so far:

```
Sub listNotCompletedTasks()

Dim cell            As Range
Dim sourceRange     As Range
Dim targetRange     As Range
Dim notCompleted()  As Variant
Dim i               As Integer
Dim lastr           As Integer

'define sourceRange
lastr = Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
Set sourceRange = Range("A2:A" & lastr)

'notCompleted is an array with all the offset cells of the cells in sourceRange
'that don't contain a "Completed" string 

i = 0
For Each cell In sourceRange.Cells
    If cell.Offset(0, 2).Value <> "Completed" Then 'if the cell in column C does not contain "completed"...
        ReDim Preserve notCompleted(0 To i)
        notCompleted(i) = cell.Value        'add cell in column A to array
        i = i + 1        
    End If
Next cell

'define targetRange
lastRow = Cells(Rows.count, "Z").End(xlUp).Row
Set targetRange = Range("Z1:Z" & lastRow)  

'copy all elements from the array to the targetRange
For i = 0 To UBound(notCompleted)
    targetRange.Offset(i, 0).Value = notCompleted(i)
Next i

End Sub
```

Expected output:
[image]

This works well. The problem begins with the second step:

```
Sub listNoDuplicatesAndNoOfInstances()

Dim sourceRangeZ As Range
Dim targetRangeB As Range
Set sourceRangeZ = Sheets("SourceData").Range("Z2")
Set targetRangeB = Sheets("TargetSheet").Range("B17")

'add all of the unique instances of a string in Z from the notCompleted() array
Do Until IsEmpty(sourceRangeZ)
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("TargetSheet").Range("B:B"), sourceRangeZ.Value) = 0 Then
        targetRangeB.Value = sourceRangeZ.Value
        Set targetRangeB = targetRangeB.Offset(1, 0)
    Else
    End If
    Set sourceRangeZ = sourceRangeZ.Offset(1, 0)
Loop

'count every instance of those strings and add the value to the respective cell to the right
Set targetRangeB = Sheets("TargetSheet").Range("C17")

Do Until IsEmpty(targetRangeB.Offset(0, -1))
    targetRangeB.Formula = "=COUNTIF(SourceData!Z:Z,Z" & targetRangeB.Row & ")"
    Set targetRangeB = targetRangeB.Offset(2, 0)
Loop

End Sub
```

The first loop (the one that adds every unique instance of the strings to column B) works. The second loop (the one that returns the number of instances of each string) does not work, only returning zeroes. The thing is, if I manually do the steps of the first subroutine (use a Pivot Table to filter out the rows I need, then copy the relevant row and paste it to column Z), and then call the second subroutine, then it actually works!

[image]

So I'm assuming the first subroutine is the culprit. A "cheap" workaround that worked for me was to copy the range in Z to another column (using `sourceRange.Copy`/`targetRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll`) and then call the second subroutine. What am I doing wrong, and is there a better way to solve this?

Comment: `=COUNTIF(SourceData!Z:Z,Z"` should be `=COUNTIF(SourceData!Z:Z,B"` and `targetRangeB.Offset(2, 0)` should be `targetRangeB.Offset(1, 0)`

Answer (score 0):

A 2D array you can copy to sheet without looping.

```vb
Sub listNotCompletedTasks()

    Dim wsSource As Worksheet, arNotCompl()
    Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long, n As Long
    
    Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SourceData")
    With wsSource
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        ReDim arNotCompl(1 To lastrow, 1 To 1)
        For i = 2 To lastrow
            If .Cells(i, "C") <> "Completed" Then
                n = n + 1
                arNotCompl(n, 1) = .Cells(i, "A")
            End If
        Next
        If n = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
        'copy array to targetRange
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "Z").End(xlUp).Row
        .Cells(lastrow + 1, "Z").Resize(n) = arNotCompl
    End With
End Sub
```

Add the formula in column C when you add the unique value to column B.

```vb
Sub listNoDuplicatesAndNoOfInstances()

    Dim wsSource As Worksheet, wsTarget As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long, n As Long
    Dim arNotCompl(), v
    
    Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SourceData")
    With wsSource
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "Z").End(xlUp).Row
        arNotCompl = .Range("Z2:Z" & lastrow).Value2
    End With
    
    Set wsTarget = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TargetSheet")
    n = 17
    With wsTarget
        For i = 1 To UBound(arNotCompl)
            v = arNotCompl(i, 1)
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range("B:B"), v) = 0 Then
               .Cells(n, "B") = v
               .Cells(n, "C").Formula = "=COUNTIF(SourceData!Z:Z,B" & n & ")"
               n = n + 1
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```